# Inserting Datagridview rows into database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, ado.net

If I want to add records to datagridview, it is okay, but I want to add records to the database which rows in datagridview.

There is a method - how am I adding Datagridview **rows**.

```
public void SepeteEkle()
{
    decimal? tutar;
    decimal? toplamtutar = 0;
    int miktarsum = 0;

    DataRow urun = dt.NewRow();

    tutar = Convert.ToDecimal(lblFiyat.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtMiktar.Text);
    bool itemfound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < dgvSepet.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == lblStokID.Text)
        {
            miktarsum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMiktar.Text);
            toplamtutar += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value) + tutar;

            dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = miktarsum;
            dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = toplamtutar; 

            itemfound = true;
        }
    }

    if (itemfound == false)
    {
        urun["Id"] = lblStokID.Text;
        urun["StokKodu"] = txtStokKodu.Text;
        urun["Ürün"] = txtStokAdi.Text;
        urun["Fiyat"] = lblFiyat.Text;
        urun["Miktar"] = txtMiktar.Text;
        urun["Toplam"] = tutar;

        dt.Rows.Add(urun);
        dgvSepet.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

I want to add database this all created **rows** using Entity Framework.

What I tried:

```
public void DatabaseSepetAktar()
{
    xstHar stokHareketModel = new xstHar();
    stokHareketModel.stharCariKod = txtCariKodu.Text;
    stokHareketModel.stharTarih = DateTime.Now;
    stokHareketModel.stharDovFiyat = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotal.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < dgvSepet.Rows.Count -1 ; i++)
    {
        stokHareketModel.masterId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        stokHareketModel.stokKodu = dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        stokHareketModel.stharGcMik1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

        using (fastCellDb db = new fastCellDb())
        {
            db.xstHars.Add(stokHareketModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error

> Validation exception

from Entity Framework.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You need to look into the `ValidationErrors` of your exception object, and drill down into the information in there. It tells you in great detail what went wrong. [Check out this excellent article](https://blogs.infosupport.com/improving-dbentityvalidationexception/) on how to easily extract that information

Comment: thanks!! ı look my exception information and see which data can't send null. THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Validation exception raises when you try to convert value with wrong type, that is due to wrong indexing. As you add a row to your DataGridView `dt.Rows.Add(urun)` using text indexing, change the indexing way from number to text everywhere: Cells[0] → Cells["Id"] etc.

And look to the line: `for (int i = 0; i < dgvSepet.Rows.Count -1 ; i++)`, it seems -1 is excess there.

Comment: this is don't fix my problem